# What is the suitable range of Lambda, eta, and alpha for Artificial Neural Network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I've finished my algorithm to apply the ANN on the C++ language, but I stack with the value of lambda, eta, and alpha, to show the best resul. I don't know if there is a rule or range that will give a good result of training.
The dataset is 4000 
The hidden neurons are 15 
**Can anyone help me please to give the reasons of chosing the best value of Lambda, Eta, and Alpha?**
Thank you very much

Comment: What do lambda, alpha and eta mean? Which ANN model have you implemented exactly?

Comment: Those are fairly standard names for learning mechanism parameters for enhanced backpropagation training.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the exact optimal values are completely problem-dependent, but I suggest using commonly-applied values (Murray Smith makes some suggestions in "Neural Networks for Statistical Modeling") and not tinkering with them.

Even today, the complaint is sometimes made that neural networks are difficult to work with because of all of the experimentation needed to optimize parameters like eta, etc.  In most situations, though, the idea is to discover a *good* approximation, not the *optimal* one.  Assuming that one hasn't chosen insane parameter values, then the only experimentation needed is adjustment of the size of the hidden layer.